# How would I define a function in python to append a word to an integer in a list depending on the integer multiple?

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function in python that would take any list of integers. If the integer is a multiple of 3 and 5, it will an in the variable a to the list. If the integer is a multiple of only 3, it will add in the variable b to the list. If the integer is a multiple of only 5, it will add in variable c to the list.

How do you reference each item in a list within an iterative function?

Here's what I have so far. Thanks

```
intList = [15, 30, 40]

def function(intList):
    a = 'Fizz'
    b = 'Buzz'
    c = a + b
for x in intList:
    if x in intList % 5 == 0 and x in intList % 3 == 0:
        intList.append(c)
    elif x in intList % 3 == 0:
        intList.append(a)
    elif x in intList % 5 == 0:
        intList.append(b)



print(function(intList))
```

Response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 18, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in function
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

The response I'm looking to get is [15, 'FizzBuzz', 30, 'FizzBuzz', 40, 'Buzz']

Comment: Please show the output your program produces, and the output you expected.

Comment: Where on Earth is `x` supposed to come from here? And what is `x in intList % 3` even supposed to mean? You don't seem to understand basic Python syntax; I'd talk to a tutoring center person or teacher to get more grounding in the basics.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

To stay close to your code, here is what you can do :

```
def fizz_buzz(intList):
    a = 'Fizz'
    b = 'Buzz'
    c = a + b

    res = []

    for x in intList:
        if (x % 5 == 0) and (x % 3 == 0):
            res = res + [x,c]
        elif x % 3 == 0:
            res = res + [x,a]
        elif x % 5 == 0:
            res = res + [x,b]

    return res

list = [1, 15, 30, 40] 

print(fizz_buzz(list))

>>> [15, 'FizzBuzz', 30, 'FizzBuzz', 40, 'Buzz']
```